# Do startups pay taxes on venture funds?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, corporate-tax-laws, delaware, investment

The corporate tax rate in Delaware is 8.7%. The federal corporate tax rate, which startups likely don't have the faculties to avoid paying, is 21%. If I'm a startup incorporated in Delaware, and I raise $100,000 on a $1,000,000 valuation, do I have to send $29,700 of that to the IRS and Delaware Department of Revenue?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Tax is paid on *profits*, not on investments / venture funds.